# Where to see the runtime errors occurred in custom application pages

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, application-pages

I created one custom application page and deployed into the sharepoint site.
When I open that application page  which resides in the _layouts folder, it is showing runtime error.
[image]

How to solved this? 
The problem occurred when i done with following steps.

1. Added one file upload control and one button and one text box.
2. After browsing any file and When we enter the path or url into the text box and click the button then the that file should be added into our give url.
3. This error occuring when I am trying to add the click event to the button. If i remove the click even then it is working fine.
   I am trying to do this based on the [MSDN example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms454491.aspx).
   But, where I can see the details of the error occured. Is it possible to trace?

Comment: 1. you need to debugg w3wp.exe process. 2.Try by removing "<SharePoint:FormDigest runat="server"/>" tag and check.

Comment: @shahjinesh11 when I remove that tag it is page is loading. But when I click on the upload button then giving this error.

Comment: Hey... Its working fine now after removing <sharepoint:FormDigest> tag. I gave wrong url thats why giving error while click on the upload file button.

Comment: gr8 to know. by removing SharePoint:FormDigest tag its working. Cheers !

Comment: but what is the <Sharepoint:FormDigest> tag?

Comment: Its is used for security. for more info [click here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.formdigest.aspx)

Comment: FormDigest is used to VALIDATE security on a page with a form to ensure the page is valid before posting data. Removing this opens a security vulnerability in the page, and potentially, the entire site. I would do more research, look at Logs, Event Viewer, etc to find out the root cause of this issue instead of just not validating the page digest.